# As we all know that, a Class is a model for creating objects, then why does static members exist as a part of class?

Tags: java

I do have a doubt that why there is a place for static members in a class as class is a name given to group of objects or it is a model for creating objects???

Comment: This is the way the language has been defined. Your term "model" is one way to talk about data abstraction. Two different tracks...

Comment: Sometimes I want to have constants for all objects of one class, so best to put it into the class as static final members.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you laune that this is the way language is defined. But, how come when static members are not part of an object, how they even exist in a class?? I think you have carefully answered my question..

Comment: Sometimes, it's necessary to have variables that are common to all objects instead of distinct in each instance of the class.

Comment: A class is as well put in the JVM memory so I do not get your point. Sorry but I have to ask: You do know the difference between class / object do you?

Comment: Hey manual in your case it is correct. But, here your are forgetting the basic definition that class is a model to create object. This means, by using class we can create objects as class is having object properties & actions already defined in it. This clearly specifies that a class is defined in any language(java, C++) for creating objects, as a class is a name given to group of objects with same behavior.

Comment: Your notion that a class is a model for creating objects is simply false. That's just what you learn at school and in real-life languages classes are what the language makes of them. In Java a class is both a model for its instances *and* a namespace  container for non-instance methods/variables.

Comment: Hello inanda, may be your answer is correct but, i have a doubt, then why are we not using object to access these static members??

Comment: Hello Marko, thanks for your new definition. It almost cleared my doubt. But, the other definition of class says that , i( Class) is a name given to a group of objects which behave in a same manner. Then your definition is going to contradict your's? what do you say??

Comment: You are just citing abstract, language-agnostic textbook definitions. They can help you grasp the basic concepts of OOP, but you are trying to push them too far. If you want the full story on the definition of "class" in Java, then hit the Java Language Specification. [Start here:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) "`Class declarations define new reference types and describe how they are implemented.`"

Comment: Hello Manuel, i clearly mentioned that i am taking baby steps in java. So, i do know the difference between class/object?? Will you help me in knowing this??

Comment: will anyone please, explain the difference between Class/Object in a simple manner so that i couldn't look for some other way for getting answer for this??

Answer (score 0):

Why not static members? A little example:
You have objects you create. But you want to count the objects you create resp. that each object has an unique ID:

```
public class TestCounter {

    private static int counter = 0;
    private int ID = 0;

    public TestCounter()
    {
        this.ID = counter++;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCounter c1 = new TestCounter();
        TestCounter c2 = new TestCounter();

        System.out.println(c1.getID());
        System.out.println(c2.getID());
    }
}
```

Output is:

0

1

I know there are a lot more examples (like a final constant for all classes, etc.), but that's one simple little example

Comment: Your answer with code, to this question is really appreciated. But why don't you make those as instance members for counting purpose?

Comment: Try that. With a variable like: private int counter = 0; you have the counter set to 0 every time. The private static int counter though is shared among all classes of type TestCounter

Answer (score 0):

The instance members can be modified (and used) by only that particular object. However a static variable can be modified by every instance of that class.

In the example by @ProgrammingIsAwesome, if we write:

```
public class Counter {

public static int count=0;

public Counter() { }

public void incrCount() 

{ count++; }

public void showCount()

{ System.out.println(count); }

}
```

and say we have

```
public class Counter {

public int count=0;

public Counter() { }

public void incrCount() 

{ count++; }

public void showCount()

{ System.out.println(count); }

}
```

If we have C1 and C2 as objects of the class and count is an instance variable, C1.incrCount(); will increase count of only C1.count and C2.incrCount(); will increase count of only C2.count. So :

```
C1.incrCount();

C2.incrCount();

C1.showCount();

C2.showcount();
```

will output:

```
1

1
```

But if count is class variable (static variable), output for same code will be:

```
2

2
```

That is C1 and C2 will increment the same variable "count" and not each `instance` of "count".